# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'size' using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I was writing a script to convert an image into ASCII art however when I run this script the console outputs the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'size'` in my resize image function.

The traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alfie\Desktop\Python\ASCII MOVIE GENERATOR\gen.py", line 15, in <module>
    f.write(ascii(f"image{count}.jpg"))
  File "C:\Users\Alfie\Desktop\Python\ASCII MOVIE GENERATOR\get_ascii.py", line 25, in ascii
    image = resize(image)
  File "C:\Users\Alfie\Desktop\Python\ASCII MOVIE GENERATOR\get_ascii.py", line 16, in resize
    old_width, old_height = image.size
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'size'
```

I have tried changing the way the image has been fed to the script however that has shown to no avail. I am expecting the script to return a properly formatted ASCII art sample.
Example of what it should return:

```
      _.-'''''-._
    .'  _     _  '.
   /   (@)   (@)   \
  |                 |
  |  \           /  |
   \  '.       .'  /
    '.  `'---'`  .'
      '-._____.-'
```

Here is the script:

```
import PIL.Image

ASCII_CHARS = ["@", "#", "$", "%", "?", "*", "+", ";", ":", ",", "."]

def pixel_to_ascii(image):
    pixels = image.getdata()
    ascii_str = ""
    for pixel in pixels:
        ascii_str += ASCII_CHARS[pixel//25];
    return ascii_str

def to_greyscale(image):
    return image.convert("L")

def resize(image, new_width = 100):
    old_width, old_height = image.size
    new_height = new_width * old_height / old_width
    return image.resize((new_width, new_height))

def ascii(image):
    try:
        image = PIL.Image.open(image)
    except:
        print(image, "Unable to find image ")
    image = resize(image)
    greyscale_image = to_greyscale(image)
    ascii_str = pixel_to_ascii(greyscale_image)
    img_width = greyscale_image.width
    ascii_str_len = len(ascii_str)
    ascii_img=""
    for i in range(0, ascii_str_len, img_width):
        ascii_img += ascii_str[i:i+img_width] + "\n"
    return ascii_img
```

Calling function:

```
while success:
    success, image = vidcap.read()
    cv2.imwrite(f"frame{count}.jpg", image)
    print ("Saved frame ", count)
    print(image)
    with open(f"ascii{count}.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(ascii(f"image{count}.jpg"))
    print("Saved ascii frame ", count)
    count += 1
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: The message "Unable to find image" doesn't appear?

Comment: Show us the **full** error traceback. You seem to removed important parts from it. Also show us how you are calling `ascii` in the first place.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yes, it does appear. Forgot to mention that.

Comment: it looks like the original error happens when you try to load the filename `str` into an image with PIL.Image.open. That hits some error (likely FileNotFound error do to an incorrect filepath), resulting in the value of `image` remaining as a filepath `str`, which then causes the error you posted about

Comment: This means that in "ascii" the variable "image" contains the path to the not existing image because the call to "PIL.Image.open" failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `try`-`except` block, you overwrite `image` (a `str` with the path to your file) with the result of `PIL.Image.open` (presumably not a `str`, but something with a `size` attribute).

The traceback shows you're trying to access the `size` attribute of a `str`, so what's happening is your `except` block is running - and then execution continues beyond, to `image = resize(image)`.

What you effectively have is a situation where the error that's reported isn't particularly helpful as it's not related to the *root* problem.

I suggest editing your try-except block as follows:

```
    try:
        image = PIL.Image.open(image)
    except:
        print(image, "Unable to find image ")
        sys.exit(1)
```

(and adding `import sys` to the top of your file) - then your script will exit immediately if there's an error, so it'll be much clearer what's going on.

Comment: I'm curious why you would use `sys.exit(1)` instead of `raise`  or better yet, not using a try-except at all

Comment: I bloody hate typos.

Comment: 1/2 @Modularizer - I'm trying not to overcomplicate things. The points of my answer are: 1) execution continues after an `except` block; 2) exception tracebacks are sometimes unhelpful and misleading because they're unrelated to the actual problem.

Comment: 2/2 The `try`-`except` being here in the first place suggests the OP wants to "print a simple message and exit" if `PIL.Image.open` fails, and `sys.exit` is a perfectly reasonable way to achieve that, especially in a basic script like this. Obviously in a big project you'd raise (or not handle) the exception and some generic code would convert that to a message, but this isn't that.